# terraform code to append existing key value pair

Tags: terraform

I'd like to append a new key-value pair to an existing yaml-based structure by using terraform.
For example I have the following yaml file:

```
urls:
  - id: site1
    url: google.de
  - id: site2
    url: bing.com
  - id: site3
    url: duckduckgo.com
```

Now I want to add a key-value pair based on some conditions.
(It's not required to write to the file. The list will be used in a loop later on)
Expected:

```
urls:
  - id: site1
    url: google.de
    secure: false
  - id: site2
    url: bing.com
    secure: false
  - id: site3
    url: duckduckgo.com
    secure: true
```

What I already tried:

```
locals {
  x = tomap({
    for k in keys(yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))):
    k => merge(
      yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))[k],
      { urls = { url = merge(yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))[k].urls[0], { secure = false }) }}
    )
  })
}
```

Works for the first url but I wasn't able to loop over the urls to get an index.
Second approach:

```
locals {
  x = tomap({
    for k in keys(yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))):
    k => {
      for l in keys(yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))[k]):
        l => l == "urls" ? <tbd> : yamldecode(file("urls.yaml"))[k][l]
    }
  })
}
```

But I wasn't able to merge or replace the structure at *<tbd>* if the key matches.
It always fails because of mismatches:

> arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `yamldecode` function converts from YAMl formatted string to HCL2, the resulting type would be `map(list(object))`; for example:

```
{ "urls" = [{id="site1", url="google.de"}] }
```

That makes it a bit more clear how to add a key-value pair to the nested `object` with a `for` expression. We need to preserve the structure, keys, and values of the original, and add a single key value pair in the nested object.

```
# map constructor and iterate through yaml map
# key = "urls", urls is list of objects
{ for key, urls in yamldecode(file("urls.yaml")) : key => [
    # inside list constructor now
    # url_attrs is single object in list of objects
    for url_attrs in urls : {
      # inside object constructor now
      # retain same key value pairs, and add a "secure" key value pair
      id     = url_attrs.id
      url    = url_attrs.url
      secure = false
    }
  ]
}
```

In HCL2 this results in (according to local testing)

```
{
  urls = [
    {
      id     = "site1"
      secure = false
      url    = "google.de"
    },
  ]
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
urls:
- id: site1
  url: google.de
  secure: false
```

I notice the logic for the `secure` boolean is a placeholder and the example code always assigned `false`, so I have done the same above.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for the simple example but is it possible to get it work for a nested list too? Like `name: [ foo: bar, urls: [{id: site1, url: google.de}, {id: site2, url: test2}]]`.

There I get an error like `This object does not have an attribute named "url".`

Comment: @Thomas Sure you can certainly ask a question around that too. Once someone answers your question, please remember to accept the answer.